# Product import failing for fields with characters like " or -

Tags: product, import, importexport

I'm working on importing some products, but when I import them, only about half make it to Catalog > Product.  I'm slowly going through them to figure out why, and I'm noticing that products with descriptions that contain double quotes or hyphens (and maybe other characters, i've only found these two so far that don't work) don't end up getting imported.  There are no errors though.

The file I'm importing is a .csv being saved in Open Office.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the file wasn't saved as Unicode-8.  Saving it that way fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the file in open office as tab delimited and import that way.

Comment: Saving it as tab delimited gives me this error:  Can not find required columns: sku